# Generate Unique Key Using Mysql + Node.Js

Tags: mysql, node.js, logic

I am developing a application where i want to create a url for end customer, to differentiate url i am creating a unique id of 6 digits using `randomstring` Package and storing it in database url pattern is like `www.xyz.com?key=ab89xd`.

But i found that they key is getting duplicated and i am not able to generate unique url.

I cannot use uuid column as it is more than 6 digits.

I cannot use primary key of the table as the key should contain number+char in the key.

How can i generate a unique key to make a unique url.

Comment: You need a longer string

Comment: You can make a random string unique if you throw away those you already had.

Comment: @RiggsFolly thanks for replay but i have to generate a 6 digit string only that is my limitation.